django_filters.FilterSet excluir todo execpto personalizado
Tengo un modelo en la base de persona con muchos campos:
models.py
class Persona(models.Model):
''' Modelo base de datos Persona '''
    nombre = models.CharField(("Nombre"), max_length=20)
    apellidos = models.CharField(("Apellidos"), max_length=30)
    dni = models.CharField(("DNI"), max_length=30)
    f_nacimiento = models.DateField(("Fecha nacimiento"), blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(("Correo electronico"), max_length=254)
    direccion = models.CharField(("Direccion"), max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    activo = models.BooleanField("Estado activo", default=True)
    # file will be saved to MEDIA_ROOT/foto/2015/01/30
    foto = models.FileField(upload_to="cv/%Y/%m/%d/", blank=True, null=True)
    cv = models.FileField(upload_to="cv/%Y/%m/%d/", blank=True, null=True)

filtros.py
    import django_filters
    from django_filters import CharFilter
    from .models import Persona
class PersonaFiltro(django_filters.FilterSet):
    Nombre = CharFilter(label="Nombre persona",
                        field_name="nombre", lookup_expr="icontains")    
    Apellido = CharFilter(label="Apellido persona",
                        field_name="apellidos", lookup_expr="icontains")
    class Meta:
        model = Persona
        #fields = ("nombre", "apellidos")
        exclude = ['nombre', 'apellidos','dni','f_nacimiento','email','direccion','activo','foto','cv','f_creacion','f_modificacion']

¿Como puedo excluir todos los campos, execpto los personalizados?
algo como:
exclude = ALL_FIELDS
Pero eso no funciona

buen dia Artemi.
puedes usar el metodo fields
ejemplo:
class PersonaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Persona
        # incluir campos especificos 
        fields = ['nombre', 'apellidos','dni','f_nacimiento','email','direccion','activo','foto','cv','f_creacion','f_modificacion']

        # incluir todos los campos
        #fields = '__all__'

NOTA:
fields y exclude no deben usarse juntos: No es posible usar fields y exclude al mismo tiempo. Debes elegir uno de los dos.
